# What was this Mouse Trap-like game with a basket, stairs, and metal parts?

Tags: identify-this-game

It was similar to Mouse Trap but it had metal parts vs. plastic. It may have been more of a maze but there was a basket & perhaps stairs. It's been driving me crazy because I loved it & want to find for my kids. I played with it in the mid 80's  so it could be from that point back.

Comment: Sure it's not Mouse Trap? Mouse Trap has a basket and stairs.

Comment: [Perhaps Flying Finnegan or Flea Circus?](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/739495/finding-old-mousetrap-game-about-circus)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it ever included metal parts, but that sounds like it could have been [crazy clock](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2726/crazy-clock-game)

Other than that possibly Flying Finnegan or Grape Escape

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is grape escape. i can only remember that and mouse trap. both games are similar in design.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a really old thread, but could you be thinking of Snafu?

Comment: Welcome to Board Games Stack Exchange! Could you please add some more information about why you think that this game in Snafu based on the poster's description?